# Move points together in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to put together a diagram in Adobe Illustrator, and I'd like to be able to move things around freely so I can find what works best. For instance, I have the following diagram

[image]

and I'd like to be able to move things around. I've been careful to put the arrow in the center of the two boxes very carefully. I'd like to be able to tie together the arrow endpoints to the boxes.

For instance, if I move one of the boxes now, I get something like this

[image]

and I have to manually correct the arrow.

Is it possible to tie the arrow endpoints to the box, so I would get something like this immediately?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to link the arrow automatically so that it is always joined to the two boxes, however if you use the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd> carefully, to make sure you select only the anchors and text you want to move, then it is possible.

An example

[image]

If you want something a bit more functional, Inkscape has a connector tool that makes this possible. It can be useful for diagrams.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works!